# Adding uid to firebase database using angularfire

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-security

I am using `angularfire` for my current project. I am having hard time configuring security rules.

Here is my data structure:

```
{
   users : {
      uid1 : { .. },
      uid2 : { .. }
   }
}
```

Security rules:

```
{ 
  "rules" : { 
     "users" : {
        "$uid" : {
           ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid",
           ".read": "auth !== null && auth.uid === $uid"
         }
     }
  }
}
```

I am using anonymous auth and "uid1" and "uid2" are nothing by `auth.uid`.

I am using following code to create

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(auth.uid));
```

Its returning alright with `$loaded` but its not creating a `uid` node under users.

Comment: Do you intend that the `$firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(auth.uid));` line create a new `/users/$uid` record?

Comment: yes. I have a feeling that I am doing it terribly wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `$firebaseObject` creates a two-way binding: anything that changes to the object in the database, will automatically be synchronized to your application.

Calling `$firebaseObject` does however *not* create an object automatically.

To create a user, you can either use the Firebase JavaScript SDK:

```
ref.child('users').child(auth.uid).set({ name: 'Vikas Singhal' })
```

Or you can create it through AngularFire with:

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(auth.uid));
obj.name = 'Vikas Singhal';
obj.$save();
```

Since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, mixing the two APIs works fine.